# [meta] Rules for subjective questions.

Tags: meta

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

How about adding this to the FAQ?

http://moms4mom.com/back-it-up

Anyone reading this has likely been guilty of using hearsay or extrapolating an answer from their body of knowledge, not out of any malice, but out of a sincere desire to help.

Codifying a principle like this would be helpful, no?

Comment: Well, I think it's a good idea, but this comment itself is opinion, and probably so are all possible answers. Is the idea that this doesn't apply to meta?

Answer (score 6):

No, no, a thousand times no.

This is about amateur brewing.  There is going to be a LOT of hearsay, a lot of unscientific anecdotes.

If you add rules about "back it up" and discourage any experience or even hearsay based discussion this site will quickly die.  I doubt that there are THAT many scientists on this site.

It is doubly unneeded, if someone makes an outrageous claim, the community will call that person on it or it will get downvoted to death.

This suggestion will create more problems than it solves.

Downvoted to express my opinion.

Comment: Seconded. Trust the community.

Comment: Agreed whole heartedly.  That's what the voting is for, and that's what is supposed to get the cream to the top right???

Comment: You've expressed your opinion quite well. The downvote just feels vindictive.

Comment: My apologies, it was not meant to be vindictive. It is a function of this format, to downvote is to express disagreement.  It was not meant to be personal and if it seemed that way it is a mistake on my part and for that I apologize.